# Can I move Windows from one computer to another if the two are hardware-identical?

Tags: windows-7, system-restore

I have two laptops that have exactly the same brand, model and hardware as each other.

Windows 7 is installed on one of them.

Would it be possible to move Windows from one laptop to the other one?

Comment: Easiest way is to swap hard drives as suggested by Olli

Comment: By windows do you mean program application windows? Or the OS?

Comment: If they are identical, why bother? Just swap the computers and save yourself the pain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is. If it's OEM license, then it's a little bit gray area, as OEM licenses are per-computer, not transferable.

You can either physically move your hard disk or clone your data (and wipe source computer, as you are not allowed to run Windows on multiple machines with same license).

There is multiple tools for cloning disks, including [CloneZilla](http://clonezilla.org/).

Comment: When you say "not allowed to run Windows on multiple machines with same license", do you mean the software will stop us from doing it?

Comment: @Pacerier this is hilariously late answer, but often, yes. You'll get "you must register this" and/or "this software is pirated" warnings.

Comment: is it hackable / bypassable?

Comment: @Pacerier SE does not support doing illegal things, so I won't help you with that.

Comment: so does that mean "yes"?